# Executing command in unix scripts and calculating timing

Tags: bash, unix

I am quite new to bash scripts. How do I execute the below command to capture the time to execute the command.

I have my deals captured in an array variable. I then am looping through the deals to execute a TradeService remote call. I want to capture the time for this call and aggregate it across all the deals.

1. What is the best way to execute this call and capture the time within my script
2. How do I manage time in my script, post aggregation of time I want to show it in hours/minutes/seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEALS="1739719, 1714630, 1733697, 1723940, 1666257, 1665239"

IFS=', ' read -ra array <<< "$DEALS"

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
        echo "Executing for DEALS $i"

RUN_TIME = time echo -n '{"source_system": "PROGA", "deal_id": $array[$i], "as_of": "2019-14-01T23:59:00Z"}' | java -jar ~/support/lib/polyglot.jar --command=call --endpoint=trades-server:10443 --full_method='TradeService/GetDeals' > /dev/null

echo "Runtime is $RUN_TIME"

done
```

Comment: The duplicates to the prior question you asked went into why you can't have spaces around the `=` in an assignment. For capturing output of `time` specifically, also see [BashFAQ #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032).

Answer (score 1):

Original answer

```
#!/bin/bash

DEALS="1739719, 1714630, 1733697, 1723940, 1666257, 1665239"

IFS=', ' read -ra array <<< "$DEALS"
total=0

for i in "${array[@]}" ; do
    echo "Executing for DEALS $i"

    startdeals=$(date +%s)
    java -jar ~/support/lib/polyglot.jar --command=call --endpoint=trades-server:10443 --full_method='TradeService/GetDeals' > /dev/null
    enddeals=$(date +%s)
    let "diff=$enddeals - $startdeals"
    let "total=$total + $diff"
    echo "Runtime for $i : $(date -d@$diff -u +%H:%M:%S)"
done

echo "Overall execution time: $(date -d@$total -u +%H:%M:%S)"
```

EDIT:
As pointed out by @Charles Duffy now we use `$SECONDS` instead `date`, assuming that execution time will be seconds-level.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEALS="1739719, 1714630, 1733697, 1723940, 1666257, 1665239"

IFS=', ' read -ra array <<< "$DEALS"

for i in "${array[@]}" ; do
    echo "Executing for DEALS $i"

    startdeals="$SECONDS"
    java -jar ~/support/lib/polyglot.jar --command=call --endpoint=trades-server:10443 --full_method='TradeService/GetDeals' > /dev/null
    enddeals="$SECONDS"
    diff=$(( enddeals - startdeals ))
    echo "Runtime for $i : $diff seconds."
done

echo "Overall execution time: $SECONDS seconds."
```

Comment: If you're only going to have seconds-level resolution anyhow, why not just use `$SECONDS` to get the number of seconds since the shell started execution? That also has a lot less performance impact than running `date`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're right, edited accordingly

Comment: As an aside, I would generally suggest `diff=$(( enddeals - startdeals ))` rather than the non-standardized `let` (which bash has for backwards compatibility with ksh88, which predates the 1992 POSIX sh standard). See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `date +%s` before and after an operation to find the time difference in seconds.  For example :

```
array=( 5 10 15 20 25 )
for val in "${array[@]}"
do
 starttime=$(date +%s)
 sleep "$val" # sleeping for '$val' seconds in each iteration
 #you should replace the above with the actual process.
 endtime=$(date +%s)
 echo "Time taken for the process is $((endtime-starttime))s"
done
```

This would give

```
Time taken for the process is 5s
Time taken for the process is 10s
Time taken for the process is 15s
Time taken for the process is 20s
Time taken for the process is 25s
```

However, I should acknowledge that it can give just up to seconds precision.

The `+%s` format string requires a special mention. The `date` manpage says :

> %s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

In essence, we just calculate the time elapsed (in seconds) with respect to a reference point in the past and then calculate the difference between end and start times. Once you have time in seconds, use well defined mathematics segregate hours and minutes.

As @ChalresDuffy pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169470/executing-command-in-unix-scripts-and-calculating-timing#comment97081707_55170327) comment, you could use the [$SECONDS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-SECONDS) internal variable to calculate the time difference. Also, [$EPOCHREALTIME](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-EPOCHREALTIME) could be used if granularity of micro-seconds is needed.

Comment: The shell is bash, so we have `$SECONDS`, no?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That is right. And it is more efficient too. Also might be of interest is EPOCHREALTIME.